# I access remote phpmyadmin but not mysql via command line

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have a distant web application and DataBase, and I want to do some test in my local machine using the remote Database.

So I changed httpd-xampp.conf -> LocationMatch:

```
    Order deny,allow
    #Require local
    Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8
    Allow from xx.xx.xx.xx
```

And add in my.ini:

```
    skip-name-resolve
```

Then I restart apache and mysql.

Now I can access to phpmyadmin without problem but not in mysql via command line nor via my web application

How can I remotely access to mysql via command line?

Thank you

Comment: How about you add a question in there?

Comment: Accessing mysql via deamon is nothing to do with apache configuration.
When you install MySQL, root user is configured by default to access via command line.
If you need to access MySQL from other environment, you need to give privileges inside it.

Comment: So you've got a remote server, with a remotely installed phpmyadmin, and you set the above config on the remote server; and you're wondering why your *local* mysql command line can't connect to the remote MySQL database?

Comment: @deceze That's exactly my problem

Comment: I think you can do it by using SSH protocol. I think you should ask your host provider to allow you using SSH access, if they allow that. The reason you are not able to access your database remotely is because of security. phpmyadmin is working on host server and has direct access to database. in case of it was a shared server.

Comment: Is it a shared server, or is it your own server?

Comment: @Blaatpraat It's my own server. Do the firewall have to do with this? If it so, witch port have to be opened?

Comment: It can be that it is a firewall-problem. Port 3306 is the default port for this. Also: when you create an user for you database (not the root account), you need to specify the host. If you put a '%'-sign, you can use that account from everywhere. Default it would only use 'localhost'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phpmyadmin is not a database. Phpmyadmin is a GUI written in PHP, helping you visually work with your database. The actual database is MySQL. MySQL is running on your remote server, likely, hopefully, behind a firewall. On the same machine is Apache serving phpmyadmin. Apache is accessible to the outside world. Phpmyadmin can access the MySQL database, because it's running locally on the same machine. You *cannot* connect to the MySQL database from the outside world, because it's behind a firewall and/or doesn't accept random connections from the internet. It has nothing to do with Apache.

And that's good. You should never publicly expose your database to the internet.

The best way to directly connect to a remote database is via an SSH tunnel. For this you need to set up SSH access to your remote system, if you haven't already, and then tunnel using something like `ssh -L 9999:localhost:3306 example.com -N`. Looks up the specifics in the ssh manual.

Comment: The reason I want to connect via command line, is to ensure that I'm able to remote access to Mysql, because the final goal is to run the web application locally but using the remote Database. So using ssh wont fit my needs!

Comment: You really want to publicly expose a MySQL database to the interwebs? O_o ... And an SSH tunnel is still a perfectly fine option. You establish the tunnel once, any app can connect through it.